# Simplifying BASH command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, solaris

I'm finding myself having to do this every once in a while, and was wondering if there's a way to **simplify** this command?

In essence, all I'm doing is copying a file and re-naming it. The functionality to create `A1, A2.. B1, B2..` is *non-negotiable* :) Thus, the nested for loop.

Note, I'm not interested in creating an actual script file. I need something quick and dirty.

```
bash> for x in {A..B}; do for i in {1..4};do cp orig.xml prefix_$x$i.xml; done;done
```

### System Info

**Platform:** `SunOS`

**Bash Version:** `GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)`

Comment: This seems simple enough, quick enough and dirty enough. The only simplification is either a script or an alias.

Comment: Good point on the alias. Only problem is that I'm sometimes not personally logged into the system. Thanks tho, I was hoping someone more creative than I could do this quicker :)

Comment: This would be a script or some shortcut file, where you can cut and paste from one xterm to another.

Comment: Well, since you concatenate the two variables, you could do `for x in {A..B}{1..4}; do cp orig.xml prefix_${x}.xml;done`, which is a bit shorter. But, if you ever need the variables in different places, the nested loop is probably better...

Comment: @OlafDietsche it could be more simple and more dirty. more quick? I don't know however..

Comment: @twalberg urr haven't seen your comment... I was testing it on the Sun server to make sure it works on bash 3.0.... :(

Answer (score 5):

it has still room to be simplified, for example

```
for x in {A..B}{1..4}; do cp orig.xml prefix_$x.xml; done;
```

this works on  **platform**:

```
SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-12 i86pc i386 i86pc

GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (i386-pc-solaris2.10)
```

Comment: +1 neat!  Works on Debian as well, fwiw.  `GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Chained brace expansions like this should work in all versions of bash that support brace expansion.

Comment: Or even: `for x in {A..B}{1..4}; do cp {orig,prefix_$x}.xml; done`